# Send query parametres with connection apache paho websocket client

Tags: java, websocket, activemq-classic, paho, broker

I have a mqtt client connecting to a broker.
My broker intercept connection to get token from it and do some works.
I want to send a token as query param when connecting.

my client connect like this:

```
        MqttAsyncClient sampleClient = new MqttAsyncClient(broker, clientId, persistence);
        MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();

        connOpts.setCleanSession(false);

        connOpts.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        connOpts.setKeepAliveInterval(MqttConnectOptions.KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL_DEFAULT);

        connOpts.setConnectionTimeout(MqttConnectOptions.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT); 
        IMqttToken token = sampleClient.connect(connOpts);
```

How can I do this? Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be possible if you modify the method `sendHandshakeRequest` in the class [WebSocketHandshake](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/internal/websocket/WebSocketHandshake.java):

```
private void sendHandshakeRequest(String key) throws IOException{

        pw.print("Upgrade: websocket" + LINE_SEPARATOR);
        pw.print("Connection: Upgrade" + LINE_SEPARATOR);
        pw.print("Sec-WebSocket-Key: " + key + LINE_SEPARATOR);
        pw.print("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: mqttv3.1" + LINE_SEPARATOR);
        pw.print("Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" + LINE_SEPARATOR);

        // TODO add the header with your token here
```

Since the method is `private` and the class is in `internal` package, you have no other choice, but compile your own custom version of the Paho library.